# remove close parenthesis in a string when parenthesis is not opened in r

Tags: r, stringr

I wanted to remove closing parentheses, ")", in a string when there is no opening parenthesis ahead. Here are examples and my desired output.

```
string1= "1548-(2), 1549)"
string2= "1401-(15~145), 153), 156"

desired_string1= "1548-(2), 1549"
desired_string2= "1401-(15~145), 153, 156"
```

*Additional:
Thank you for the answers, it works well but it doesn't for the following case:

```
additional = "1543-(2, 6), 1548-(2), 1549), 1334-(1~5),  1401-(15, 145)"
desired_additional = "1543-(2, 6), 1548-(2), 1549, 1334-(1~5),  1401-(15, 145)"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create a function to get the location of the parentheses and if there is any unbalanced one, then the `length` of one of them would be different, use that location in `substr` or `str_sub` to change it to `""`

```
library(stringr)
f1 <- function(str1) {
   i1 <- str_locate_all(str1, '\\(')[[1]][,1]
   i2 <- str_locate_all(str1, '\\)')[[1]][,1]
   i3 <- seq_along(i2) > length(i1)
   if(any(i3)) {
      i4 <- i2[i3 ]
      str_sub(str1, i4, i4) <- ''
   }
   return(str1)
  }
```

-testing

```
f1(string1)
#[1] "1548-(2), 1549"
f1(string2)
#[1] "1401-(15~145), 153, 156"

f1("((a))")
#[1] "((a))"

f1("(a))")
#[1] "(a)"
```

Using the updated 'additional'

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(additional, "(?<=\\)),", perl = TRUE)[[1]], 
       f1), collapse=",")
#[1] "1543-(2, 6), 1548-(2), 1549, 1334-(1~5),  1401-(15, 145)"
```

Comment: Thank you! can you take a look at the additional example?

Comment: @Johnlegend2 I updated the post with the new example

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `stringr` package

```r
fun <- function(x) {
  library(stringr)
  open_cnt = str_count(x, "\\(")                      # counts opening parentheses
  close_cnt = str_count(x, "\\)")                     # counts closing parentheses
  if(close_cnt > open_cnt){ 
    diff_i = (open_cnt+1):close_cnt                         # indexes differences
    diff_loc = str_locate_all(x, "\\)")[[1]][diff_i,1]      # locates differences
    paste0(unlist(str_split(x,""))[-diff_loc], collapse="") # rebuilds string
  } else {x}
}
```

```r
fun(string1)
#[1] "1548-(2), 1549"
fun(string2)
#[1] "1401-(15~145), 153, 156"
fun("((( 0__0 ))))))))))")
#[1] "((( 0__0 )))"
```

Comment: Thank you! can you take a look at the additional example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookbehind and lookahead:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(str, "(?<=,[^)]{1,10})\\)(?=,|$)", "")
[1] "1548-(2), 1549"          "1401-(15~145), 153, 156"
```

Here we remove only those `)`s that (i) follow a `,` followed by 1-10 characters which are *not* `)` and that (ii) precede either a `,`or the end of the string.

Data:

```
str = c("1548-(2), 1549)", "1401-(15~145), 153), 156")
```

**EDIT**:

If the data is more complicated, like this:

```
str = c("1548-(2), 1549))", "1401-(15~145), 153) ),) 156)")
```

you can use *negative* lookbehind:

```
str_replace_all(str, "(?<!\\([^)]{0,10})\\)\\)?", "")
[1] "1548-(2), 1549"          "1401-(15~145), 153, 156"
```

Here we remove one or two consecutive `)`s **if** there is no opening round parenthesis `(` to the left at any distance between 0 and 10 characters (which must not include any `)`).

Comment: I like the easy one-liner solution with an existing function, but the solution so far has a limitation. It doesn't always properly remove `)`s when there is more than one `)` to remove in a string. How would you change it to fix `str = c("1548-(2), 1549))", "1401-(15~145), 153) ),) 156)")`?

Comment: Thank you! can you take a look at the additional example?